# sorting on formatted date in jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am trying to sort a table which has column like 01 Apr 2010. I am using below to apply sort

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#dataTable").tablesorter();  
});
```

But its not working for the dates of format dd MMM yy. Can any one suggest how can i apply this format for sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [example parsers page](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html), it shows you how to create a custom parser.  You can parse dates like that with `new Date(date)` or `Date.parse(date)`. I don't have the means to test it, but something like this should work:

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'ddMMMyy', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // parse the string as a date and return it as a number 
        return +new Date(s);
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
});
```

All that's left for you to do is specify the sorting method using the `headers` option:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("dataTable").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { // <-- replace 6 with the zero-based index of your column
                sorter:'ddMMMyy' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```